# Ember-cli addon read configurations

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I am trying to create an ember-cli addon and I want this addon to include custom command. This part I have already done by creating a `lib/commands` file structure and including the script that will run the command then used `includedCommands` in the addon `index.js`.

The part I am struggling with is I want the command to be able to read a configuration file within the host applications directory. How can I do this? If I could find out the host apps absolute path I suppose I could parse a file using built in node tools but how do I find this path?

If there are better ways to accomplish this task I am all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your commands `run` function, you can access `this.project` which provides details about the project.

What you want to use is `this.project.root`.. it's the root directory of the project.

Comment: Ah, this is perfect and seems more clean than my method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem. Don't know if it is the best way. So I am able to obtain the absolute process path in node just by using `process.cwd()` Then I can simply append a config file name to the end of the string to get my config file absolute path.

If there are any ember-cli specific ways that I should be doing this then please let me know.